# Caret range and package-lock.json: how to get latest non-breaking versions with them?

Tags: javascript, npm, package-lock.json

I got what `package-lock.json` is standing for, but I don't understand how is caret range work after adding this file?

Say I have a package (`my-module`) that I want to have all new non-breaking versions without specifying new versions manually. I install latest version and this is the result in `package.json` file:

`"my-module": "^4.1.1"`

However `package-lock.json` is also getting updated with fixing the version of `my-module` to `4.1.1`.

Next time a new version comes out of `my-module`: `4.1.2`. Running `npm i` will *not* install it as the version in `package-lock.json` is fixed to the old version.

### Question

How can I achieve that `npm i` will download latest non-breaking version of `my-module` without creating new `package-lock.json` file all the time? Did this file just invalidate using caret range?

Answer (score 4):

We came up with the idea of using `preinstall` functionality of `package.json`.

So under in your `package.json` file under scripts tag you add:
`"preinstall": "npm update"`.

Since `npm update` only updates packages affected by the caret range syntax you can have both `package-lock.json` and latest updates.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not fond of just posting pieces of documentation *verbatim*, I feel it is the best source to explain why what you're asking for is exactly what **package-lock.json** was designed to NOT NECESSARILY DO:

> 1. **package-lock.json** is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the **node_modules** tree, or **package.json**.
> 2. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent    installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of    intermediate dependency updates.

WHEN **package.json** is fed into `npm i` the result of the operation is a filesystem **node_modules**, consistent with all the dependencies as declared in the **package.json** file.

This operation DOES NOT produce the same result all the time: even when using the exact same **package.json** file. And there are good reason why `npm i` was designed to do this, specifically:

- If a new version of a direct semver-range package may have been published since the last time your packages were installed, and thus a newer version will be used.